# Increasing keyboard repeat rate in KDE

Tags: keyboard, kde, repeat-rate

**How can you increase the rate of the keys you are allowed to type in Ubuntu's KDE?**

Comment: Nitpick: KDE is a desktop environment independent of Ubuntu (it runs on Arch, for example), so did you mean "[Kubuntu](https://kubuntu.org/)" by "Ubuntu's KDE"? Anyway, this question belongs more to Unix&Linux, and has some [newer answers there](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/384390/kde-keyboard-repeat-delay-rate-settings-dont-work-have-no-effect).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In **K → Computer → System Settings → Keyboard & Mouse → Keyboard**, under **Keyboard Repeat**, there is a setting called **Rate**, which you can increase by dragging the slider.

On KDE 4.13.3 (Ubuntu Trusty 14.04.5), **Keyboard Repeat** can be found in:
**K → Computer → System Settings → Hardware → Input Devices → Keyboard**

[image]

Comment: This is strange. I do not have the keyboard -option at the left-hand side for some reason. I have only the other four. - I use the "glassy" kde in Ubuntu 9.10. **What is your distro?**

Comment: I use various ones, I'm not sure if I installed it on my LFS build or Arch, but I think it was Arch: http://archlinux.org

Comment: Or use `xset r rate [delay ms] [rate]`

Comment: Note that there's a [bug with Wayland due to which changing the keyboard repeat settings has no effect](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/384390/kde-keyboard-repeat-delay-rate-settings-dont-work-have-no-effect).

Answer (score 0):

It seems the last update for Kubuntu 20.04(at the moment of writing) fixed the bug, so, now, the changes are saved.

However, is there any way to increase the possible repeat rate and **save** the settings?

I've been using this command:

```
xset r rate 250 100
```

But the repeat rate is reset even during the same session. So, I have to run that command again.